# How to display server side variable inside a TreeNode's Text Attribute?

Tags: asp.net, treeview, code-behind

.cs file:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string s;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s = "Director";
    }
}
```

.aspx file:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
      <Nodes>
           <asp:TreeNode Text="<%=s %>"></asp:TreeNode>
      </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

this outputs <%=s%> instead of the value of s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't use those types of expressions in server tag attributes, per, ["Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework" (MSDN)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112), under the "*`<%= ... %>` displaying expression*" heading:

> Remember that the displaying expression cannot be used in the
>   attributes of server controls. This is because the .NET Framework
>   directly compiles the whole expression instead of the displaying
>   content as the value to the attribute.

If you do want to set the value of that node, in your example, you'd have to set it like this:

```
public string s;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    s = "Director";
    TreeView1.Nodes[0].Text = s;
}
```

Comment: Lovely, that was exactly what I needed!! Ta-da!!